# Laravel 5 Custom Query Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5, I am trying to do a customer query. My code is like so:

$params = array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'criteria1' => $criteria
        );

```
    //Define the SQL
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $this -> _taskTableName .' 
    JOIN ' . $this -> _userTableName .' ON 
    ' . $this -> _userTableName .'.id = ' . $this -> _taskTableName .' .client_id 
    WHERE notes LIKE \'%:criteria%\' OR name LIKE \'%:criteria1%\' ';


    //Exeute the search
    $tasks = DB::statement(DB::raw($sql),$params);
```

Except I keep getting this error, even when I remove DB::raw, and I've tried DB::select as well.

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: :criteria (SQL: SELECT * FROM tasks 
JOIN users ON 
users.id = tasks .client_id 
WHERE notes LIKE '%:criteria%' OR name LIKE '%:criteria1 %' )
in Connection.php (line 647)
at Connection->runQueryCallback(object(Expression), array('criteria' => 'Devin', 'criteria1' => 'Devin'), object(Closure))
in Connection.php (line 607)
at Connection->run(object(Expression), array('criteria' => 'Devin', 'criteria1' => 'Devin'), object(Closure))
in Connection.php (line 450)
```

Does anyone have an idea why this happening and how to fix?

Comment: Did you try using eloquent models? the query doesn't look so complicated (unless you simplified for the post), why go for raw sql instead of using models? As for the exception, it seems when you are enclosing the variable inside % %, it might be taking it literally as the criteria itself rather than a variable

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `DB:select()` with the `$params` array as a second argument, like this :

```
$params = array( 'criteria' => $criteria, 'criteria1' => $criteria );

//Define the SQL
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $this -> _taskTableName .' 
JOIN ' . $this -> _userTableName .' ON 
' . $this -> _userTableName .'.id = ' . $this -> _taskTableName .' .client_id 
WHERE notes LIKE \'%:criteria%\' OR name LIKE \'%:criteria1%\' ';


//Exeute the search
$tasks = DB::select($sql, $params);
```

Comment: No, same result. The only difference in yours is you are not usign DB:;raw

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $this -> _taskTableName .' 
        JOIN ' . $this -> _userTableName .' ON 
        ' . $this -> _userTableName .'.id = ' . $this -> _taskTableName .' .client_id 
        WHERE notes LIKE \'%?%\' OR name LIKE \'%?%\' ';
    DB::select($sql,array($criteria,$criteria));
```